# MPAndroidChart Remove space when right axis is disabled

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I use this code to hide right axis:

```
 linechart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```

[image]

but it has a space like margin of chart (Line chart width is `match_parent` without margin)

Is there any way to remove this space and make the chart fill to the right edge of screen?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this space is better for keep. But if you really want to remove, I found this method that can help:

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(leftOffset,topOffset,rightOffset,bottomOffset);
```

You can try this method by custom the view port to remove the blank space.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you disable the right axis by using

```
// Java    
linechart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

// Kotlin
linechart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
```

After disabling the right axis there will still be some blank space remaining. All the surrounding padding of the chart can be removed using:

```
// Java
linechart.setMinOffset(0f);

// Kotlin
linechart.minOffset = 0f
```

Please also make sure that you don't have any extra offset set by using one of these earlier:

```
// Kotlin
lineChart.extraLeftOffset

lineChart.extraTopOffset

lineChart.extraRightOffset

lineChart.extraBottomOffset
```